# No access to files in subfolders when removing extension in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to access some php files which are located inside some subfolders. I'm using a .htaccess file, which removes all the .php extensions. 
Here is the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.net/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.net/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I have to say that I just copied this .htaccess file from a tutorial, because I have no experience in this area.

So a quick example: I can access `www.example.net/folder/myphpfile.php` , but I get a "file not found" error when I try to access `www.example.net/folder/anotherfolder/myphpfile.php` .

But it works when I delete the `.htaccess` file.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried accessing www.mysite.com/folder/myphpfile without the .php extension

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$` – you are specifically requesting here that the path that is matched does _not_ contain a `/`.

Comment: @CBroe , is that wrong? Can You Tell me how its correct?

Comment: You want it to work for files in “subfolders”, so not allowing a slash – which happens to be the path separator, and is therefor necessary to “go into” any folder in the first place – doesn’t make much sense, right?

Comment: Your subdirectory issue can be fixed by skipping the rewriterule.

`# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, skip next two rules
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=1]

# Pretty URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.+?\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Its located at: example.com/folder . And I did Enter Example.com/folder/folder2/phpfile into my browser. It also does not work When i add php at the end

Comment: This htaccess should be placed in root I.e. a level above folder.

Comment: This is weird. Now after I put the .htaccess to the root level it even can't find for example `example.com/folder/file.php`. So I switched back to the old .htaccess and created another .htaccess inside my subfolder and now it works fine